# JS moment doesn't add time

Tags: javascript

```js
var dateTimeFrom='2022-10-30 01:00'
dateTimeFrom = moment(dateTimeFrom).add(60, "minutes").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
console.log(dateTimeFrom)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The correct answer is '2022-10-30 02:00', but the result I get is '2022-10-30 01:00', as if moment doesn't add 60 minutes.

Can you run this code and see what result you receive?

Comment: Working as expected [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qBorMod?editors=0012)

Comment: Works fine for me. What is the result of `moment(dateTimeFrom).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")`?

Comment: Like the OP I get `2022-10-30 01:00` as the output in Firefox v103. (Same in Louys' example)

Comment: time zones are not optional if you want to do real datetime arithmetics

Comment: It's probably best to disclose: your browser and its version, your operating system, and even your locale and local time zone.

Comment: Works for me on jsfiddle - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbm4tr3g/) , using Chrome 103.0.5060.114

Comment: Isn't Oct 30 2022 a DST/"Summer Time" switch day?

Comment: @evolutionxbox have you tried it for 10-28?

Comment: @Pointy Yes. It shows `2022-10-28 02:00`

Comment: Right, I bet it's a time switch date in at least some locales.

Comment: @Pointy if the OP is in the UK, 30th October is when BST ends. https://greenwichmeantime.com/articles/calendars/bst-dates/

Comment: My output is `2022-10-30 02:00`.  Chrome 103 Windows 10, EN-US, GMT-4 America/Toronto (EDT)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. On October 30, 2022 Daylight Saving Time ends here in Israel.

At 2 AM clocks are turned backward 1 hour to 1 AM.

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Which daylight saving time?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).